# Save animation as gif in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, save, gif

I am trying to save an animation as animated GIF.
My plot is similar to the given code below.
I created it with animated line too.

The problem is that:
When I defined my figure as `f=figure` or `figure(1)` it creates the .gif file properly.

However, instead of plotting my figure in separate screen using "figure" command, I have to plot in an axes on **MATLAB GUI** axes as the given figure.

I tried it with: `f=(handles.axes_threeDOF);`, But when I use this function, the gif file creates different part of the screen.

Could you help me to solve my problem?

```
numpoints = 500; 

x = linspace(0,4*pi,numpoints); 

y = square(x); 

y2 = 3 +square(x+1);

f = figure 

h = animatedline('Color','b','LineWidth',2); 

h2 = animatedline('Color','r','LineWidth',2);

grid on;

axis([0,12,-3,+6]) 

for k = 1:numpoints 

  addpoints(h,x(k),y(k)) 

  addpoints(h2,x(k),y2(k)) 

  drawnow  

  % Capture the plot as an image 

  frame = getframe(f); 

  im = frame2im(frame); 

  [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256); 

  % Write to the GIF File 

  if k == 1 

      imwrite(imind,cm,'test.gif','gif', 'Loopcount',inf); 

  else 

      imwrite(imind,cm,'test.gif','gif','WriteMode','append'); 

  end 

end
```

I want to create a gif of this animation:
[image]

But it creates as given [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLeEn.gif) with this function " f=(handles.axes_threeDOF)"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem:

`f = handles.axes_threeDOF` gets the handle of the **axes** instead of getting the handle of the **figure**.

Since I don't know the name of your figure, I can't give a perfect solution.
You may try the following options:

1.Find the name of the **figure**, and use something like: `f = handles.figure_threeDOF;`
 2. Use `f = gcf();`, assuming there is only one figure.
 3. Use `f = handles.axes_threeDOF.Parent;` assuming the figure is the "Parent" of the axes.

---

**Update:**

After `im = frame2im(frame);`, you need to crop the relevant part of the image:
Something like: `im = im(36:884, 928:1800, :);`

There are more robust solution than using fixed indices, but it requires some knowledge about the internal structure of the figure.

---

Here is a code that reproduce the problem (instead of figure handle, `f` gets axes handle):

```
numpoints = 500;
x = linspace(0,4*pi,numpoints);
y = square(x);
y2 = 3 +square(x+1);
f = figure;
h = animatedline('Color','b','LineWidth',2);
h2 = animatedline('Color','r','LineWidth',2);
grid on;
axis([0,12,-3,+6])

for k = 1:numpoints
    addpoints(h,x(k),y(k))
    addpoints(h2,x(k),y2(k))
    drawnow

    %%% Test %%%
    %The following code demonstrates the problem.
    %f = gca(), returns a handle to the axes, instead of the figure.
    %You should remove the following line for the code to work properly... 
    f = gca();
    %%% Test %%%

    % Capture the plot as an image
    frame = getframe(f);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);

    % Write to the GIF File
    if k == 1
        imwrite(imind,cm,'test.gif','gif', 'Loopcount',inf); 
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,'test.gif','gif','WriteMode','append'); 
    end
end
```

---

Result of correct code (without `f = gca();`):
[image]

Result of **wrong** code (with `f = gca();`) - getting axes handle instead of figure handle:
[image]

Comment: Hi Rotem! Thank you for your answer. When I add f=figure and gca() to my code, it still create my figure in a different window. I want to see this figure in my GUI axes (axes_threeDOF).
Actually I can plot it in the GUI axes using f=(handles.axes_threeDOF). The problem is exporting it as gif. It does not save whole axes like that https://ibb.co/MnTR9fc

Comment: I think you didn't understand my answer. The code that uses `gca()` reproduces your problem. Using `gca()` is wrong!!!

Comment: Did you try `f = gcf();`? Did you try `f = handles.axes_threeDOF.Parent`?

Comment: I edited my post, just to make it clear that `f = gca();` is a "bug". (I added the "bug" for demonstrating the problem). I also added the two results, so you can see that `f = gca();` gives result that is similar to the result you are getting.

Comment: Yes I tried f = handles.axes_threeDOF.Parent.  Also I used gcf.  Actualy it creates gif  better than my previous versions. 
But the problem is here: it create gif whole screen like that:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=502289108384
. I just want to make a gif from my figure.

Comment: It's not the "whole screen", but the "whole figure". In case the figure is maximized to the "whole screen", you are going to get the whole screen... I think an ad-hoc solution can be cropping the relevant part of the image. Something like: `im = im(36:884,928:1800,:);`